Using gradcam to plot heatmap the detection image by custom trained model of YOLOv6 and YOLOv7
Can anyone help me with how to use Grad-CAM plot a heatmap for detection images using a custom-trained model YOLOv6 and YOLOv7? I have done ploting the heatmap for YOLOv5 and YOLOv8 but the code did not working with YOLOv6 and YOLOv7.
